# Delegate method call which has params

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I have a number of WCF calls which I would like to have a `try` `catch` around them. Instead of copying the same block of `try` `catch`, I would like to delegate the function call.

Here is my sample original function (cut down);

```
public DTO_Echo_Response SendEcho(DTO_Echo_Request request)
{
    try
    {
        return Proxy.SendEcho(request);
    }
    catch (System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException)
    {
        throw new Communication_Error("Communication Error");
    }
}
```

I would like something like the following:

```
public DTO_Echo_Response SendEcho(DTO_Echo_Request request)
{
    // invoke Process(Proxy.SendEcho(request));
}

public _DTO_BaseResponse Process(Func myFunction)
{
    try
    {
        return myFunction();
    }
    catch (System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException)
    {
        throw new Communication_Error("Communication Error");
    }
}
```

I have visited many articles and tried many different things which were way off the mark.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close. Try this:

```
public DTO_Echo_Response SendEcho(DTO_Echo_Request request)
{
    return Process(() => Proxy.SendEcho(request));
}

public TResult Process<TResult>(Func<TResult> myFunction)
{
    try
    {
        return myFunction();
    }
    catch (System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException)
    {
        throw new Communication_Error("Communication Error");
    }
}
```